Struggling to get a transaction included in the blockchain using official Solana Rust TPU client
I'm trying to write a proof of concept rust program to try to send a transaction using the TPU client provided by the official GitHub solana repo, with the goal of reducing the time between intially sending the transaction and it being included in a block.
My question is what am I missing as a reason why my transaction might not be getting included by the leader, even after he has acknowledged that he has received it.
I'm utilizing a TPU client using the QUIC protocol.
Here's the source code of the rust package:
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "testtpu"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[patch.crates-io]
solana-program = { path = "../solana/sdk/program" } 
solana-zk-token-sdk = { path = "../solana/zk-token-sdk" } 

[dependencies]
solana-client = { "path" = "../solana/client" }
solana-tpu-client = { "path" = "../solana/tpu-client" }
solana-rpc-client = { "path" = "../solana/rpc-client" }
solana-sdk = { "path" = "../solana/sdk" }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
tokio = "1.37.0"

main.rs:
use {
    // bincode::serialize,
    solana_client::{
        connection_cache::ConnectionCache,
        tpu_client::{TpuClient, TpuClientConfig},
    },
    solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient,
    solana_tpu_client::tpu_client::{ DEFAULT_TPU_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE, TpuSenderError },
    solana_sdk::{
        signer::keypair::Keypair,
        pubkey::Pubkey,
        system_instruction,
        message::Message,
        transaction::Transaction,
        compute_budget::ComputeBudgetInstruction,
        commitment_config::CommitmentConfig,
        signature::Signer,
    },
    std::{
        sync::Arc,
        env,
        str::FromStr,
        time::Instant,
    },
    dotenv::dotenv,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    dotenv().ok();

    // Now you can access the variables from .env file
    let base58_private_key = env::var("PRIVATE_KEY").expect("PRIVATE_KEY must be set");
    let keypair = Keypair::from_base58_string(&base58_private_key);

    let compute_unit_limit = env::var("COMPUTE_UNIT_LIMIT").expect("Compute unit limit must be set");
    let compute_unit_price = env::var("COMPUTE_UNIT_PRICE").expect("Compute unit price must be set");

    let compute_unit_limit: u32 = compute_unit_limit.parse().expect("Compute unit limit should be an integer");
    let compute_unit_price: u64 = compute_unit_price.parse().expect("Compute unit price should be an integer");

    let rpc_client = Arc::new(RpcClient::new_with_commitment(
        "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com".to_string(),
        CommitmentConfig::confirmed(),
    ));

    let connection_cache = ConnectionCache::new_quic("connection_cache_test", DEFAULT_TPU_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE);
    let tpu_client = match connection_cache {
        ConnectionCache::Quic(cache) => TpuClient::new_with_connection_cache(
            rpc_client.clone(),
            "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
            TpuClientConfig::default(),
            cache,
        ),
        ConnectionCache::Udp(_) => Err(TpuSenderError::Custom("Matched incorrect type for connection cache".to_string())),
    }.unwrap();

    let transaction_start_checkpoint = Instant::now();

    let recent_blockhash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();
    println!("recent blockhash: {:?}", recent_blockhash);

    let tx = {
        let from_pubkey = keypair.pubkey();
        let instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
            &from_pubkey,
            &Pubkey::from_str("<somebase58pubkey>").unwrap(),
            1_000_000,
        );
        let message = Message::new(&[
            ComputeBudgetInstruction::set_compute_unit_price(compute_unit_price*200),
            ComputeBudgetInstruction::set_compute_unit_limit(compute_unit_limit/200),
            instruction,
        ], Some(&from_pubkey));
        Transaction::new(&[keypair], message, recent_blockhash)
    };

    //TODO: maybe fetch recent blockhash inside of the loop, because it is only valid for approximately 60-90 seconds

    loop {
        // Below is the same version of the code but using the rpc client:
        // let result = rpc_client.send_transaction(&tx);
        // let result = match result {
        //     Ok(_) => true,
        //     Err(_) => false
        // };
        let result = tpu_client.send_transaction(&tx);
        println!("send tx result: {:?}", result);
        if result {
            break;
        }
    }

    let transaction_sent_checkpoint = Instant::now();
    println!("Confirming transaction (commitment level: processed):");
    rpc_client.confirm_transaction_with_spinner(
        &tx.signatures[0],
        &recent_blockhash,
        CommitmentConfig::processed()
    ).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Confirmed transaction successfully (commitment level: processed), confirmation took {:.2?}, in total {:.2?}",
        transaction_sent_checkpoint.elapsed(),
        transaction_start_checkpoint.elapsed(),
    );
    println!("Confirming transaction (commitment level: confirmed):");
    rpc_client.confirm_transaction_with_spinner(
        &tx.signatures[0],
        &recent_blockhash,
        CommitmentConfig::confirmed()
    ).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Confirmed transaction successfully (commitment level: confirmed), confirmation took {:.2?}, in total {:.2?}",
        transaction_sent_checkpoint.elapsed(),
        transaction_start_checkpoint.elapsed(),
    );
}


Even after the tpu_client.send_transaction method returns true, sometimes the transaction is still not included in a block.
Of course this can happen due to the fact that the leader has decided not to include the transaction, potentially due to a not high enough prioritization fee.
If I understand correctly, the QUIC protocol uses ACK, so if the send_transaction method returns true, than the leader has confirmed that he has received the transaction packet.
So in that case the only factors remaining, affecting the chances of the transaction being included in the next block, are the COMPUTE_UNIT_LIMIT and COMPUTE_UNIT_PRICE.
However this behavior seems to be inconsistent, even if I increase the compute unit price by orders of magnitude.
As far as I gathered from reading the Solana source code is that incoming QUIC packets are prioritized solely based on the compute unit price, and after a certain rate limit the other packets are discarded. So theoretically, the higher the price I set, the better my chances.
Maybe another factor can be if I overestimate the compute units used by the transaction too much with the COMPUTE_UNIT_LIMIT I specify?
Also I saw that the recent congestion fix for Solana, which you can see here, in the changes in core/src/banking_stage/forwarder.rs a line was added to only forward packets from staked nodes. So does this mean that if I stake some of my solana, this should fix the problem, or increase the priority of the transaction due to stake-weighted QoS? Or maybe the leader accepts QUIC packets only from Validator nodes, which have staked their solana?
I know that all these questions can be answered by reading the solana source code thoroughly, and I'm doing it but it's not easy. So I was hoping if someone more familiar with the solana rust codebase can answer some of these questions, and possibly enlighten me to some factors in the decision of a leader to include or not to include a transaction that I have missed entirely.
Here are the relevant parameters in .env:
PRIVATE_KEY=
RUST_BACKTRACE=0
COMPUTE_UNIT_LIMIT=101337
COMPUTE_UNIT_PRICE=421197


Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

Hello. I'm solving the same problem.
they say that QoS does not matter if the validator has little stake sol.
it’s good if there are 2-3 million stake sol

so I know how to solve this.
but I see some bots successfully landing their transactions even when the network is heavily loaded.
It is possible that some validators may change the order of transactions. Then it looks like a big problem. because big validators have united and are abusing traffic

please let me know how you get on. Thank you
